# How To Make Bootstrap 3 ignore specific types of controls

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using VS2013, WebForms, and an older version of Telerik ASP.Net controls (2012.xx) . I have not upgraded Telerik because of budget.

I am currently tasked with updating a tired, slow, clunky, non-responsive interface that is largely based on tables and Telerik Controls. In particular there are a lot of RadGrid and RadDatePicker controls sprinkled throughout the pages in the application. While I am replacing the Telerik controls where i can, some things (like RadGrid ) are just too hard to replace.

I am having problem where a RadGrid will look fine in some cases, but in others (even on same page) it suddenly looks all wrong. I am sure it has to do with BootStrap 3 and Telerik controls "fighting" for control over CSS, but i don't have enough time to dive into the reasons and try to "fix" it correctly.

Instead, I am wondering if there is any way to add a class to a control that is on my page which will tell Bootstrap to "ignore this control....don't mess with it at all"?  If push comes to shove I can make a custom theme for Telerik Controls, but I am uncertain that it will actually solve the problem.

I am totally new to Bootstrap, so not really sure how it works behind the scenes, just know that it does a pretty nice job overall but it is not playing with others very nicely right now.

Any suggestions / guidance would be really welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Paul

Comment: In my experience, RadGrids are unaffected by bootstrap, unless you add bootstraps classes to them. And I hate to say, I have a lot of experience with that lately :P. Are you adding any classes to the RadGrids table element?  Edited to add--I feel for you if you have to do any style adjustments to the train-wreck that is telerik generated code.

Comment: Ted, Thanks for the feedback, that is what i have been reading, and hoping for! On a prayer, I moved my radgrid out from inside any tables or divs etc and when the page is first rendered, it looks exactly right....but no data in it yet. When the user selects a choice from a dropdown list, on the postback i set the datasource etc, and it gets populated with data.....and that is when it blows up....no headings, all the wrong styles everything.....if i unselect the dropdownlist.....then it displays fine.   Only "Odd" thing about grid is that i am using column groups so i have a 2 row header.

Comment: I think you should consider upgrading, lately there have been fixes about issues stemming from bootstrap, as well as some responsive features:
http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/aspnet-ajax/release-history/q3-2013-version-2013-3-1015-474367365
and
http://demos.telerik.com/responsive-web-design-aspnet/default.aspx since Q1 2014